# confusion in custom attributes and Manage attributes in magento admin

Tags: php, magento, custom-attributes

I am totally confused in attributes please help me. I am continuously doing this attributes task for 3 days but no output from my side.

Here is a screen shot:-
[image]

Here Admin Panel:-[image]

NOw this I want grey and pink value in my product list page.C:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml

means the value of custom attributes in my product list page. 
please help me how should I get that value.....

Using Manage attributes/attributes set i got the  value:

```
$size= $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('size')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ;//this are simple attributes
$color= $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color1')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ;//this is simple attributes
```

See this is my configurable product :-
http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/672/6732454339.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create "configurable products" to be able to do what you want.
Example will allow you to create a clothes product with different colour variants:

1. Create a new attribute "Colour" in "Manage Attributes" and add
   your colours
2. Create a new attribute set "Clothes" in "Manage
   Attribute Sets"
3. Add your Colour Attribute to the Attribute set
4. Create a new Product on "Manage Products"

   - Select your "Attribute set" (Clothes)
   - "Product Type" is "Configurable Product"
5. Once you completed the product details save your product and go back to edit
   it again.
6. Click the last Tab "Associated products" and using the "Quick simple product creation" tool, create the colour variations.
7. Save, reindex and check your product on the frontend.

You should not need to edit any code. I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks @gergely, i have created configurable products.but i get the dropdown menu in configurable  product on frontend.but value dont get it. why?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "but value dont get it." ?

Comment: There is nothing in the dropdown? Check if all products are in stock and enabled (including the simple ones)

Comment: in my configurable product front end description page size and color drop down does not have any value blank drop down is there.In that drop down respective color and size should come

Comment: see i am attaching one image in my querstion

Comment: hm, are you saying that the Colour dropdown is empty on the image above? Is the size dropdown populated correctly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32153/discussion-between-user1988-and-gergely-varga)